# Is it possible to emulate Kotlin android Android with a browser?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am looking forward to create an Android app with Kotlin. 
But I can not use Android Studio or other IDEs. I am using the Amazon AWS Cloud9 IDE now.

I have found there is WebView and read articles, but I still cannot figure out how it works.

It is possible to emulate the UI on the web or is it only for web application development?

Comment: The WebView is used to display web content within an Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebView framework allows you to specify viewport and style properties that make your web pages appear at the proper size and scale on all screen configurations for all major web browsers. You can even define an interface between your Android app and your web pages that allows JavaScript in the web pages to call upon APIs in your app—providing Android APIs to your web-based application.

Consider using these alternatives to WebView if your app falls into the following use cases:

1. If you want to send users to a mobile site, build a progressive web app (PWA).
2. If you want to display third-party web content, send an intent to installed web browsers.
3. If you want to avoid leaving your
   app to open the browser, or if you want to customize the browser's
   UI, use Chrome Custom Tabs.

[More details](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps)